# Require a solution for full screen image slide show using cakephp and foundation framework

Tags: php, html, css, zurb-foundation-6, cakephp-4.x

code below is long but really straight forward only require code to put forward ability to slide from first slide to last slide to that return to first slide to traverse.

```
<div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="Favorite Space Pictures" data-orbit>
                <div class="orbit-wrapper">
                    <div class="orbit-controls">
                      <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
                      <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>
                </div>
                    <ul class="orbit-container">

                        <?php
                            foreach($employers as $employer){

                                echo '<li class="orbit-slide">
                                        <figure class="orbit-figure">
                                            '.$this->Html->image($employer['image'], ['alt'=>'employer image',
                                                                                "class"=>"orbit-image"]).'
                                            <figcaption class="orbit-caption">'.
                                                $employer['brief'].
                                                $employer['name'].
                                                $employer['desg'].
                                                $employer['created'].'
                                            </figcaption>
                                        </figure>
                                    </li>
                                ';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <nav class="orbit-bullets">
                <?php
                $i=0;
                foreach($employers as $employer){

                    echo '<button data-slide="'.$i.'">
                        <span class="show-for-sr">First slide details.</span>
                        <span class="show-for-sr" data-slide-active-label>Current Slide</span>
                    </button>';
                    $i++;
                }
            ?>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

code below is to slide thumbnail images traverse from first to last and return to first as above but with thumbnails that show product slide 4-5 at one go. Below code must show 4-5 thumbnails with small text and traverse as timer and button click play a role.

```
<div class="ecommerce-product-slider orbit" role="region" aria-label="Favorite Space Pictures" data-orbit>
                <ul class="orbit-container">
                    <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
                    <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>

            <?php

            foreach($sectorsandcourses as $sectorandcourse){

                echo '<li class="orbit-slide">
                        <div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-4 large-up-5 align-center">
                            <div class="column">
                                <div class="product-card">
                                    <div class="product-card-thumbnail">
                                      <a href="#" class="th">'.              
                                          $this->Html->image($sectorandcourse['image'], ['alt'=>'Image for sector and courses',
                                                                                          'style'=>'width:100%;']).'</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <h2 class="product-card-title"><a href="#">'.$sectorandcourse['sectors_and_courses'].'</a></h2>
                                    <span class="product-card-desc">Product Description</span>
                                    <span class="product-card-price">'.$sectorandcourse['count'].'</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>';
            }
            ?>
                </ul>
                <nav class="orbit-bullets">
                    <?php
                    foreach($sectorsandcourses as $sectorandcourse){

                        echo '
                            <button class=data-slide="0">
                                <span class="show-for-sr">First slide details.</span><span class="show-for-sr">Current Slide</span>
                            </button>';
                    }
                ?>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

so both are different do not get confused be kind to put forward a relation between both but not to confuse them as same since one is a full screen slide show next one is thumbnail slideshow.

vision to make :
[fullscreen slideshow](https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/fullscreen-image-slider.html)
[thumbnail slide show](https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/ecommerce-product-slider.html)

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your issue is. Do you mean that the animation stops after the second slide / image? If so please check if you have included otion-ui which is required for orbit slider.

Comment: issue is what you wrote, slide show does not work after second slide /image. what to do about it? i have slide show but does not go further after second image. i really need slide show to work properly for two slide shows one a fullscreen slide show and again for a thumbnail slideshow. thanks.

Comment: Add motion-ui. See the docs.https://get.foundation/sites/docs/orbit.html#basics

Comment: thanks man that has solved much of it but still can't progress through second slide. what to do from here ? reply thanks.

Comment: Generally it should work with motion-ui. Please provide a codepen where we can see the actual problem.

Comment: yes of course give me a few minutes to update question. thanks. s

Comment: i have made an update to previous question and to look for that solution to resolve fullscreen slide show and thumbnail slideshow to move forward from second slide.

Comment: I see no codepen in your question here.

Comment: ok i'll update codepen i.e.  describe code

Comment: Sigh, your question contains too much text. Please make it clear, concise and short. It's currently impossible to understand what exactly your problem is. And with codepen I mean https://codepen.io

Comment: code.pen does not affect code because code is written with PHP, CakePHP precisely.

Comment: In your example the PHP part is not really relevant for this.

Comment: tell me one way you could have understood that code would have images show up as slide show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbit has been discontinued i suggest use carousel with bootstrap.

Comment: Orbit Slider was not discontinued and still lives in Foundation 6 ;-)

Comment: Read deep about foundation 8. Has been deprecated.

Comment: Foundation 6? Not sure what you mean. Not even Foundation 7 is released ;-) It is not deprecated anymore in the latest 6.x version =)

Comment: DEPRECATION NOTICE:
Orbit has been deprecated, meaning that it is no longer supported. There's no need to worry though as we decided to leave it in Foundation if you choose to continue using it. We explain it here.

There are other great options if you need an image slider. A lot of them have features based on Orbit and may have added one of two more features.

This image slider is really slick: Slick Carousel. It has all the features Orbit has and can also be used as a carousel for single image sliding.

Comment: you guys banned my question posting privilege  for all wrong reason.

Comment: These are the old v5 docs. Please check the current v6 docs where we undeprecated the orbit slider. And still, you can use any other slider like swiper which can do more than orbit (which is a very simple slider, don't expect too much from it).

Comment: https://get.foundation/sites/docs/orbit.html is for the current v6 version. No need to take a look at the old v5 docs.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question the following?

> i only require to work with that code that works to enable slide show beyond seond slide and return to first slide

If so please shorten your complete question to this (loop, start with first slide after last).

This already works by default as `data-infinite-wrap` is `true` by default.

https://get.foundation/sites/docs/orbit.html

https://get.foundation/sites/docs/orbit.html#js-options

You did not specify the exact Foundation version (6.x.y, x and y are needed) and we would need a https://codepen.io to see your actual problem.

Also try to remove `is-active` from your output. This may be the cause. And only provide generated html code so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: hi, [code pen](https://codepen.io/siddhant-prabhakar/pen/abzPPeN)  link look at code.

Comment: so i tried to put first after last but that did not work. so, i removed "is-active" but timer stopped working. slide show is at first slide for both slide shows i.e. fullscreen slide show and thumbnail slideshow. get back ASAP really need an answer because i wanna push that code. Thanks anyone who would reply.

Comment: Your codepen does not work. You use the slick script. This is not the orbit slider. I suggest ot take some time to create a proper small reproducible and working testcase as codepen.

Comment: slick did not work because there was no need to use any of that code only code that works is that i replace foundation deprecated image slide show with another that would work.

Comment: slick was not helpful as name suggest.